# Kids' sci-fi movie where a young girl sacrifices herself

Tags: story-identification, tv, young-adult, hard-sci-fi

I was watching a sci-fi movie or an episode of some TV series as a kid in the early 90s. The only thing I can remember after all these years was that there was a group of kids in a spaceship or on another planet. At some point a young girl (possibly not even a teenager) sacrifices herself by jumping into what was either an alien device or a portal of sorts. After that one of the kids consoles a crying peer by saying something along the lines of "She gave her life for our freedom".

If I remember correctly, there was a scene (probably the jump itself) where the protagonist flies down the shaft and it looks sort of like an optical illusion:
[image]

I know this isn't much information, but I'd like to see this thing again because I remember it was my first encounter with the concept of sacrificing one's life when I was a child and it freaked me out for weeks.

Comment: This really isn't a lot to go on, can you remember why she sacrificed herself? How did the sacrifice save them? Can you remember what any of the characters look like? What was the device? Why were they out in space/another planet? If you remember anything else, especially plot wise, can you edit your question to add that detail in?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734745/movieconnections/?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I remembered a small detail, but that's probably as much as I can pull out of my memory.

Comment: @pori I had no idea the short story was filmed, but I guess I should not be surprised. It's probably not it though, or at least not the Twilight Zone episode.

Comment: You sure it wasn't the Austin Powers [time machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpzpgTObH_U)? ;-D

Comment: This was mid 90's rather early 90's but could it possibily be a TV show featuring kids/teens on a spaceship called  Hypernauts? Never actually seen myself so can't say if any episodes match check out the IMDB page here... https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115210/

Comment: @Möoz - I think you mean ["Time Machine"](https://media.giphy.com/media/qs6ev2pm8g9dS/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 2):

After some more searching, I believe it could have been the Season 1 finale of Space Cases (created by Peter David and Bill Mumy of Babylon 5).

It somewhat fits my description - one of the main characters dies while saving other crew members, which is followed by an emotional scene where the crew mourns her death. I definitely watched this show, so the only major detail missing is the psychedelic void. But human memory is a strange thing, I'll have to see if this wasn't from another episode.

A funny thing is that Catalina who died was played by teenage Jewel Staite whom I loved very much in Firefly many years later. I wonder if it has something to do with having seen this series as a kid...